# PHP override weak function return type coercion

Tags: php, php-7, type-coercion

According to the PHP documentation on Strict Typing found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict)

> By default, PHP will coerce values of the wrong type into the expected scalar type if possible. For example, a function that is given an integer for a parameter that expects a string will get a variable of type string.

I'm curious if there is a way to override this functionality to customize the way that the coercion is done.

For example

```
function getResponse() : \Namespace\Response {
    return []; // Ideally, this would be coerced into a Response object.
}

. . .

namespace Namespace;

class Response {
    public $data;         

    public function __construct(array $arr)
    {
        $this->data = $arr;
    }

    public static function __coerce($value)
    {
        if (! is_array($value)) {
            throw new \TypeError('Wrong type during coercion.');
        }

        return new self($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the idea of "customizing" coercion. Strict typing is either `on` or `off`. And if you ever made it past the first sentence in the docs, you would have seen, that strict typing is to be switched on on a per-file basis: `declare(strict_types=1);`

Comment: btw. if you want strict return types, you should do Java.

Comment: @AlexKarshin I'm trying to override the functionality of coercion. I understand that strict typing can be turned on or off. I'd like to be able to type hint the return type for a function, and return a type that is not that type hinted type, and when doing so have a function in the type hinted type that i can override to handle external types being changed to that type.

Comment: the only solution would be to download source code and edit it the way you want it, then compile and use. AFAIK, there's no way to otherwise.

Comment: My suggestion would be to not rely on coercion at all in your code - finally PHP has strict types! Embrace it =)

Comment: @RobbieAverill I love that strict types exist in PHP now, however it would be nice to have a hybrid of the two. Why not multiple strict types? Like being able to return an array or a response, but nothing else? Things like that that I feel could come in useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written my own implementation to do this in PHP, since none existed. This is how it works.

These are the two base functions.

---

1. **The `multiReturnFunction` function.** (Used for calling global functions and anon functions)

```php
/**
 * Call a global function and use type coercion
 * for non-registered return types. 
 *
 * @param  closure $closure    The function to execute. 
 * @param  string  $returnType The registered return type.
 * @param  array   $params     The parameters to pass to the function. 
 * 
 * @return mixed The result of the function to execute.
 */
function multiReturnFunction($closure, $returnType, ...$params)
{
    $val = $closure(...$params);

    if (gettype($val) === 'object') {
        if (get_class($val) != $returnType) {
            if (method_exists($returnType, '__coerce')) {
                $val = $returnType::__coerce($val);
            } else {
                throw new \Exception(
                    'Returned value does not match the return type defined, '.
                    'and no __coerce function is visible.'
                );
            }
        }
    } else if (gettype($val) != $returnType) {
        if (method_exists($returnType, '__coerce')) {
            $val = $returnType::__coerce($val);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception(
                'Returned value does not match the return type defined, '.
                'and no __coerce function is visible.'
            );
        }
    }

    return $val;
}
```

The `multiReturnFunction` function will call a closure and use the `__coerce` function of the return type class to coerce the return type if the resulting return type does not match.

**An Example of the `multiReturnFunction` function**

- Define the class that we will be using, and be sure to give it a `__coerce` function.

  > Note: `__coerce` functions take a single variable for the object that we will be trying to coerce into this class type. The function must be declared static.

  ```php
  class MyClass
  {
      private $data;

      public function __construct(array $value)
      {
          $this->data = $value;
      }

      public static function __coerce($value)
      {
          if (! is_array($value)) {
              throw new \Exception(
                  'Returned value does not match the return type defined.'
              );
          }

          return new self($value);
      }
  }
  ```
- Next, you will need to call the `multiReturnFunction` function using your class and an anonymous function.

  ```php
  $resultingMyClass = multiReturnFunction (
      // Multi return type function.
      function($name, $age) {
          // Here you can return either a MyClass instance, or an array.
          // All other types will throw an exception.

          return [$name, $age];
      },

      // Return Type, any other type will be coerced through this class.
      MyClass::class,

      // Function parameters.
      'Nathan', 23
  );
  ```

---

2. **The `multiReturnMethod` function.** (Used for calling class methods)

   ```php
   /*
    * Call a class method and use type coercion
    * for non-registered return types. 
    *
    * @param  object  $obj        The object to call the method on.
    * @param  string  $method     The method to call on the object.
    * @param  string  $returnType The registered return type.
    * @param  array   $params     The parameters to pass to the method. 
    * 
    * @return mixed The result of the method to execute.
    */
   function multiReturnMethod($obj, $method, $returnType, ...$params)
   {
       $val = $obj->{$method}(...$params);

       if (gettype($val) === 'object') {
           if (get_class($val) != $returnType) {
               if (method_exists($returnType, '__coerce')) {
                   $val = $returnType::__coerce($val);
               } else {
                   throw new \Exception(
                       'Returned value does not match the return type defined, '.
                       'and no __coerce function is visible.'
                   );
               }
           }
       } else if (gettype($val) != $returnType) {
           if (method_exists($returnType, '__coerce')) {
               $val = $returnType::__coerce($val);
           } else {
               throw new \Exception(
                   'Returned value does not match the return type defined, '.
                   'and no __coerce function is visible.'
               );
           }
       }

       return $val;
   }
   ```

The `multiReturnMethod` function will call a class method and use the `__cooerce` function of the return type class to coerce the return type if the resulting return type does not match.

**An Example of the `multiReturnMethod` function**

> Note: We will use the `MyClass` class we created before as a return type.

- Define a class that we can use to call the class method on.

  ```php
  class MRFClass {
      function callMe($name)
      {
          return [$name, 1, 2, 3];
      }
  }
  ```
- Call the `multiReturnMethod` function using your class and an anonymous function.

  ```php
  $resultingMyClass = multiReturnMethod (
      // The object that we will be calling the
      // class method on.
      new MRFClass(),

      // The class method to call, by name.
      'callMe',

      // The return type to coerce to.
      MyClass::class,

      // The function parameters.
      'Nathan'
  );
  ```

---

Both of these methods can be used to force strict return type functions, that accept multiple return types that can be coerced to the return type on a per-class implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible** as this is evalue on language level on compile time.

Only thing you can do is override parent return type:

```
public function getResponse(): []  // though parent has "Reponse" type
{
    return [];
}
```